# How can I write the following sentence in passive voice?

Tags: passive-voice

I would like to keep the note about the line of code for (Tim):

> The following module cannot be approved because, Eugene have reviewed it and found following mistakes: 'Eugene's quote here'.

Can I say something like this (?):

> The module is being reviewed by Eugene with following notes: 'quote here'.

Comment: 1. _Eugene **has**_ 2. _module **has been** reviewed_ 3. use issues instead of mistakes - sounds less confrontational

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few issues

1. Eugene **has**
2. module **has been** reviewed
3. I suggest you use *issues* instead of *mistakes* - it sounds less confrontational

So

> The module has been reviewed by Eugene and (the) following issues (were) found:
>     1. ...
>     2. ...